# Referencing the collection your working on within LINQ

Tags: linq

I am working with linq, and im wondering if there is any way that I might reference the collection I am working on from within my linq code? What I am looking for is something like this:

```
let result = (from t in someCollection 
              where t == something
              select t).Where(res => res.start == THIS.Min(temp => temp.start))
```

So what I want to achieve in this query is that the THIS variable should provide a reference to the collection that the where clause is being applied to:

```
(from t in someCollection 
              where t == something
              select t)
```

There are lots of ways to get around this problem, but I am specifically interested in a way of using a reference to the collection in use. Hope some of you know something about this!

Thanks!

Comment: In this case, this is a bad idea, as `Min` will scan through your entire collection once for every item in said collection, looking for the minimum value, even though the minimum value won't change. You'd be better off finding the minimum once and then checking against it in a separate query.

Comment: Agreed, but say that you have to do some kind of other comparison for every element in your collection to every other element. Is some there some way of doing a thing like this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do what your example states is like this:

```
var minValue = someCollection.Min(x => x.start);
var result = from t in someCollection
    where t.id > 5 // replace this line with your "where t == something"
    where t.start == minValue
    select t;
```

> but say that you have to do some kind of other comparison for every
>   element in your collection to every other element. Is some there some
>   way of doing a thing like this?

If you really need to compare one item with every other item in the list, you could pattern your code like this:

```
var result = from t in someCollection
    where t.id > 5 // replace this line with your "where t == something"
    let minValue = someCollection.Min (x => x.start)
    where t.start == minValue
    select t;
```

The problem with the second example is that every item you visit in your `someCollection` it will be forced to recalculate the minValue.

Now, here's a completely contrived example that illustrates having to access the entire collection while accessing each member of the collection.  It simply goes through a list of items and outputs each item along with all the other items that have lesser dates:

```
var eventItems = new[]
{
    new { Name = "alpha", DateCreated = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1) },
    new { Name = "bravo", DateCreated = DateTime.Today.AddDays(2) },
    new { Name = "charlie", DateCreated = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1) },
    new { Name = "delta", DateCreated = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-5) },
    new { Name = "echo", DateCreated = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3) },
    new { Name = "foxtrot", DateCreated = DateTime.Today.AddDays(3) },
    new { Name = "golf", DateCreated = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-4) }
};

var results = from item in eventItems
    where item.Name.Length > 2
    let prevDays = eventItems.Where (i => i.DateCreated < item.DateCreated)
    select new
    {
        Name = item.Name,
        CurrentDate = item.DateCreated,
        PreviousItems = prevDays
    };
```

The output:

[image]

Perhaps one of these examples will help you with your exact problem.

Comment: Thanks for a great set of examples. I was able to find a solution for my problem using one of them!